# Ubuntu 20.04 Keyboard navigation of Desktop Environment and Folders

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, dock, desktop-icons

I am unable to directly navigate the folders on my desktop environment using only the keyboard. Searching over internet, I couldn't find a shortcut to select a folder on the desktop (Example Recycle bin) and even after using the mouse to highlight/select on folder, I am unable to toggle between folders using the arrow keys or access the software pinned on the dock.